# Binding stylesheet.css into html doesn´t work

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, linker

I really hope you can help me because I spent 2 days now looking for my mistake. I want to link an external css stylesheet into my html website but the website opens without css affecting it. I already validated both codes and checked spelling 1000 times, still not working. I tried with FF Chrome and IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="bilder/favicon.png" />
    <title>Die Hauskatze</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Stylesheet:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body{
    background: url(bilder/background.jpg);
}

img {
    border: 4px black;
}
```

Comment: Is the href attribute correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your css file is probably is in another folder than your `bilder` folder. Be sure to specify this in the path.
If the css file is in a css folder for example, you need to go one folder up then in you bilder folder.

```
body{
    background: url("../bilder/background.jpg");
}
```

for the border you need to specify the border 'style' (solid, dotted, etc)

```
border: 4px solid black;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

Comment: Oh my god I thought the css document uses paths starting from the html document location. Thanks now the background is working! But I still have problems with the Image border, it does not appear

Comment: you have to specify the type of border
`border: 4px solid black`

Answer (score 0):

For starter you can try to add quotes to your URL here

```
body{
    background: url(bilder/background.jpg);
}
```

change it to:

```
body{
    background: url("bilder/background.jpg");
}
```

If that doesn't help it is quite likely that your path is wrong.
You can see it inside your developer console once the page is being loaded.
In case of wrong url you will get an error that the img file was not found.

Comment: Unfortunally this did not help. I checked the syntax before and it is right. I also checked the path about 300 times it is everything ok.

Comment: When I use the css code inside my html document it works, just as an external sheet it does not